# Trigger my function on load as well as scroll

Tags: jquery

i have wrote a script with changes an objects yPos on scroll, this is working perfect for me but what i would like it for the code to run on load too, as the elements are in the wrong place when it loads.

so here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
        $(".think:in-viewport").each(function() {
            $window = $(window);
            $elementOffset = $('.think').offset().top;
            console.log($elementOffset);
            $('html.no-touch div[data-type="backgroundthink"]').each(function(){
                var $bgobj = $(this);
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop() - $elementOffset) / $bgobj.data('speed'));
                    console.log(yPos);
                    var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
                    $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and within this function i would like

```
 var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop() - $elementOffset) / $bgobj.data('speed'));
                    console.log(yPos);
                    var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
                    $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
```

to run on load of my page (so reresh etc)

any help is greatfull

Thanks

Working code:

```
//Viewprt trigger
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
        $(".think:in-viewport").each(function() {
            $window = $(window);
            $elementOffset = $('.think').offset().top;
            $('html.no-touch div[data-type="backgroundthink"]').each(function(){
                var $bgobj = $(this);
                var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop() - $elementOffset) / $bgobj.data('speed'));
                console.log(yPos);
                var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
                $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow.. that's a lot of scroll event bindings...

Comment: Hang on... you have a scroll event handler attached within a scroll event handler?

Comment: @Mish and Jason, i know i need to clear it up ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you have a scroll event attached within scroll event handler. You can trigger `scroll` event after page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
  $(window).scroll(); // This will trigger scroll event
});
```

Comment: thank you, forgot about that, after clearing up the scoll's it worked must have been the 2nd one... added final code above